# Ubuntu 20.04 applications folder

Tags: startup-applications

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it seems to be working OK so far. However I've noticed that */usr/share/applications* no longer shows apps installed, in so far as you could view and run them from there. What I see now are [desktop configuration files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXzjw.jpg), all shown with a default icon. I noticed the same thing when running Live Ubuntu. I don't see the point of this.

It's not that much of an issue in that I can still use the '*Show Apps*' button on the panel to find and launch an application. But in previous versions of Ubuntu, that applications folder was useful on showing the properties of an app so you could see the command needed to launch it from the terminal. That no longer seems possible. Or did something go awry with my installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour indeed has changed in Ubuntu 20.04. Now, the file manager shows `.desktop` files as what they are: `.desktop` files. It does not anymore show them as launchers.

It is indeed very personal: for me, this is not an issue. It is a welcome change. The file manager serves to manage files on your drive. So I prefer these launchers also be shown as the files they are. Launching apps indeed is designed to happen in an other place: in the Activities or Applications overview.

So conclusion, do not worry: there is nothing wrong with your installation :-)

Comment: Can't agree. Don't understand that *.desktop* files have anything to do with my desktop. All the *Activities View* shows are open windows so you can switch between them. It's never done anything else AFAIK. I don't see how you find/launch an application from there. And it still does not address the question how I now find the correct command to launch an application.

Comment: I indicated this is personal. I personally find the current behavioul more logical. If you need to find out the correct command, open and inspect the `.desktop` file, which you also needed to do with the old behaviour. Only, it was more difficult to open the file as a text file back then...